# gson parsing not returning proper object

Tags: android, json, gson

Trying to parse the following json using gson in my android app but givien it's structure can't work it out.

JSON

```
[
{
    "city": {
        "country": "Canada",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Toronto",
        "province": "Ontario"
    }
},
{
    "city": {
        "country": "Canada",
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Ajax",
        "province": "Ontario"
    }
}
]
```

JAVA

```
public class LocationCityList {

    private List<LocationCityContainer> cities;


    public List<LocationCityContainer> getTrends() {
        return cities;
    }
    public void setTrends(List<LocationCityContainer> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

}
```

The following returns an array of proper length but after that I can't work out how to get city objects themselves.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(getJSONData(url));       
LocationCityList[] objs = gson.fromJson(r, LocationCityList[].class);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured it out. Java code needs to be as follows.

```
public class LocationCityList {

LocationCity city;

public LocationCity getLocationCity(){
    return city;
}
```

}

```
public class LocationCity {
private String name;
private String id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Too many commas. Try this json (notice I removed the commas after Ontario):

```
[
{
    "city": {
        "country": "Canada",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Toronto",
        "province": "Ontario"
    }
},
{
    "city": {
        "country": "Canada",
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Ajax",
        "province": "Ontario"
    }
}
```

]

I find it beneficial when having json issues to run my json through a validator. http://jsonlint.com/ is an excellent resource.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the json when pasting it in, my actual json is allot longer and format is correct when using a json parser.